# Accessing DB2 from Pharo smalltalk

Tags: db2, odbc, pharo

How do I access DB2 on Windows from Pharo smalltalk?
I researched the ODBC option, but the code seems to be outdated as the following script didn't work in my Pharo 6.1.

```
Gofer new
  squeaksource: 'ODBC';
  package: 'ConfigurationOfODBC'; load.
  (Smalltalk at: #ConfigurationOfODBC) load.
```

When I execute the code above I got an exception doesNotUnderstand: #selector
in RBParser>>externalFunctionDeclaration. Looks like currentScope variable is not defined.

Are there other options, other than ODBC?

Comment: Edit your question to show the Db2-version and fixpack and bitness, and , the error you get from ODBC. Db2 on Windows supports ODBC and JDBC and CLI and command-line access, and has bindings for 'C' and other languages.   Prove that you can get the ODBC access working from the odbcad32 tool with Db2 before you attempt to get it working from Smalltalk.

Answer (score 1):

Full credits to Esteban Lorenzano who provided the answer on Pharo mailing list:

```
Metacello new 
  smalltalkhubUser: 'PharoExtras' project: 'ODBC';
  configuration: 'ODBC';
  version: #bleedingEdge;
  load.
```